# calcular las coordenadas XY del conjunto de vértices de un polígono regular

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, struct, estructuras

ESTA VEZ TENGO otro problema,tengo entendido en el siguiente programa que se debe calcular la rotación de los polígonos con un for y comprendo la iteración de inicializar i en 0, y n siendo la cantidad de lados del polígono, lo que no logro entender es la parte de la incrementación, sé que debe ir de '2π/n', pero no comprendo como hacerlo, por favor me podrían ayudar?
también presento dudas con el cálculo de los vértices, seé que se tiene que calcular con r=a/cos del angulo, donde el ángulo sería pi/n, donde n es el num de lados de nuestro polígono esto es solo para calcular la distancia, pero no tengo idea de como aplicarlo para los vértices, sé que se utiliza el for.

por favor ayuda.

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Vector2
{
    / *
     * QUE HACER:
     * Declarar los miembros necesarios para representar un vector en R2
     * /
    float x;
    float y;

} Vector2;

Vector2 * calculate_vertices (int n, apotema flotante, centro flotante_x, centro flotante_y, rotación flotante)
{
    Vector2* vértices = (Vector2*) malloc (n*tamaño de (Vector2));

    / *
     * QUE HACER:
     * Calcular las coordenadas XY de los 'n' vértices de un polígono regular con el
     * apotema dado, coordenadas del centro y ángulo de rotación.
     * Almacenar las coordenadas en 'vértices' (una matriz de Vector2)
     * /
     for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++2 3.1416/n)
     {
         /* code */
     }

    devolver vértices;
}

void print_vertices_xy (Vector2 * vértices, int n)
{
    int i;
    para (i = 0; i <n; i ++)
        printf ("% + 0.4f% + 0.4f \n", vértices [i] .x, vértices [i] .y);
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    si (argc <6)
    {
        printf ("¡Muy pocos parámetros! Uso: \n");
        printf ("./ Practice03 n apotema centro_x centro_y rotación \n");
return -1;
    }
    int n = atoi (argv [1]);
    float a = atof (argv [2]);
    flotar cx = atof (argv [3]);
    flotador cy = atof (argv [4]);
    flotar r = atof (argv [5]);
    si (n <3)
    {
        printf ("Número de vértices no válido. \n");
        return -1;
    }
    si (a <= 0)
    {
        printf ("Apotema no válido. \n");
        return -1;
    }

    Vector2 * vértices = calcular_vertices (n, a, cx, cy, r);
    print_vertices_xy (vértices, n);
    libre (vértices);
    
    return 0;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros que tu tienes para cada punto serían la longitud del radio del círculo en el que se encuentra el polígono y el ángulo que formaría una línea imaginaria que pasase por el punto en cuestión respecto del eje horizontal. Es decir, tus datos de entrada están en coordenadas polares, mientras que los datos de salida deberían estar en coordenadas cartesianas. Tienes que programar la conversión.

Así, las coordenadas `x` e `y` del punto serían:

```
x = r * cos(ang);
y = r * sin(ang);
```

Ahora bien, ¿Cómo obtenemos los incrementos de ángulo? Como sabemos que el polígono está inscrito en un círculo y sabemos que el perímetro de un círculo son `2*PI` radianes, basta una división para calcular el *paso* o incremento de ángulo entre un punto y el siguiente:

```
float paso = 2 * PI / n;
```

Y con esto ya tenemos todos los ingredientes necesarios:

```
Vector2 * calculate_vertices (int n, float radio, float centro_x, float centro_y)
{
    Vector2* vertices = (Vector2*) malloc(n * sizeof(Vector2));

    float paso = 2 * PI / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        float angulo = paso * i;
        vertices[i].x = centro_x + radio * cos(angulo);
        vertices[i].y = centro_y + radio * sin(angulo);
    }

    return vertices;
}
```

Bueno, realmente falta un detalle. En la firma de la función original se recibe la apotema, es decir, la distancia mínima de cualquier lado del polígono al centro del círculo en el que está inscrito. Así que hay que buscar la forma de obtener el radio del círculo a partir de este parámetro.

No es mi intención resolver todo el ejercicio sin resolver tu duda, la cual ya está resuelta, así que yo paro aquí.